# how do i do code navigation in dreamweaver, like ctrl+click in eclipse?

Tags: javascript, navigation, dreamweaver

In eclipse if I do ctrl + click on a function, it will take me to the function definition.
Is there any shortcut like that in Dreamweaver (CS5) to goto the javascript function definition, when i click on a function call?

This is the biggest trouble i have in Dreamweaver :(

Answer (score 1):

The closet thing that Dreamweaver has to the goto definition is:
Right-Click in code view -> Functions -> "list of functions here"

The list of functions are only the functions that are actually defined in the current file, include files aren't searched. Of course this is of limited functionality, but besides doing a site wide search for "function myFunctionName", this is what is available.

Comment: hmm.. very sad that dreamweaver doesnt provide simple ctrl + clik :(